My Windows (not server) computer can be accessed with IPv6 but not IPv4 (telnet and HTTPs)?
I have a Windows 11 Pro computer with IIS enabled. It has public IPv4 1.2.3.4 and 1:2:3:4 (from https://whatismyipaddress.com/). I setup an IIS website and route my domain to my server with Cloudflare (with an A and an AAAA records). However, the DNS record didn't work until I deleted the A record. When I tried using telnet, I can connect to the  IPv6 (both 80 and 443 ports) but not IPv4 ("Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed").
What is the problem here? Below are my setup:

Cloudflare: A record to 1.2.3.4 and AAAA record to 1:2:3:4, both for the same host dns.example.com.

I know my computer supports both IPv4 and IPv6 because https://whatismyipaddress.com/ shows both my IPs correctly.

I setup Port forwarding in my router (my computer is at 192.168.1.2):




Windows Firewall has World Wide Web Services (HTTPS Traffic-In) enabled (and I also tested with the entire Windows Firewall turned off so I guess this is not an issue).

IIS website works. telnet 1:2:3:4 443 and telnet 1:2:3:4 80 works. Entering https://[1:2:3:4]/ into browser works too. However, IPv4 for both telnet and browsers don't work.


UPDATE:

192.168.1.2 and http://127.0.0.1/ works as well so probably not an IIS issue since those are IPv4.



Does your router have a public address? What other websites show doesn't tell you anything about your router nor about your computer – external sites are always going to show you some kind of public address almost by definition, but what they cannot tell is whether that address is dedicated to you[r router] or whether it is shared, and that's the important part here. (For example, they show your computer a public IPv4 address that's certainly not your computer's – if it were, you wouldn't need port forwarding – and the question is whether it's at least dedicated to your router.)



In your telnet tests, are you testing from inside your network (i.e. inside the NAT boundary) or from outside? With NAT this matters.


@grawity_u1686 hi, I do not understand the 1st question. Isn't 1.2.3.4 my router's public address (because that's what the Internet sees)? Do you mean I may be behind carrier-grade NAT? As per question 2, yes I was testing from inside, I will try from a VM now.

Right, the point of the first question was that what the internet sees is not necessarily your router's address – you could indeed be behind the CGNAT and the internet could not tell the difference. (Just like it already can't tell the difference between your computer having its own IP versus being behind regular NAT.) Only your router itself knows whether it has been assigned a public IP address or not, so you should compare the 1.2.3.4 from websites with the "WAN IP" shown in the router's status.

@grawity_u1686 you are right! The router WAN IP address is different and it even shows NAT: on. So I guess there is no way I can get my computer to the Internet with IPv4 right?

@grawity_u1686 Also I tested from an online service, same thing happens: IPv6 can be accessed but not IPv4. I think we have the answer, I am behind a carrier-grade NAT.

Most likely yes – although "NAT: on" doesn't describe CGNAT (since the router is unaware of it); most likely it only describes the router's own NAT, which is usually attached to the WAN interface specifically.
